# XRandR cannot add the mode

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

```
root@localhost:~# xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
```

It was working all fine with my previous kernel but now its all broken.

EDIT  1: I think what could possibly the reason behind my problem is that the required resolution has somehow got transferred to a new display with the name VIRTUAL1. Below is the screenshot of `xrandr -q`[image]

So even if you could tell me how to delete this VIRTUAL1 display that I am unable to, I think it could do.